# ASP.Net Core is not throwing an Exception when running in Debug Mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and ASP.NET Core.  One of the APIs (Account) depend on a cache service that uses Redis.

```
public AccountController(Cache.Contracts.ICacheManager cacheManager)
{
     _cacheManager = cacheManager;
}
```

When Redis is not running, the api/account should not work since Cache Service should make a connection to Redis.

In the startup class:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {      
     loggerFactory.AddConsole();
     loggerFactory.AddDebug();
 }
```

When requesting the api/account

**Running the project from Visual studio**

It gives the following:

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
```

**When running from powershell by** using `dotnet run`:

[image]

This is also the Exception Settings

[image]

**Question**

Why errors are not thrown in Visual Studio case? I need to know what errors are causing my application to break.

Comment: One issue is that if you just run your app using "start without debugging" in your VS, do you get any compiled error? For the unhandled exception, we often enable it under Debug->Windows->Exception settings, but if the code was not really called during debugging or it has the compiled error, it would not throw the exception messages.

Comment: There is no complication errors, also I have checked all the _Common Language Runtime Exceptions_ in Exceptions Window

Comment: If you view the output windows, and select the "debug" dropdown list, could you get the exception? I know that it can show the Exception in the output window without the Exceptions throw during debugging under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Output window->Exception messages after you enable/disable the JIT debugging or others.

Answer (score 0):

The error gets thrown during the request pipeline. So, you might not directly see it.

Add the developer exception page `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` to see details instead of a generic message and/or add a custom middleware to catch all the exceptions which happen on each request. In this case you can set a breakpoint and inspect the exception or log it:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
});
```

Important, add this middleware at the beginning, before any other middleware or .UseMvc etc...

Comment: Is there any way to have Visual Studio break immediately when the exception is thrown in user-code **without** needing to resort to setting the Debugger Exception Settings window to break-on-all-thrown-exceptions?

Comment: You mean in your controller for example? You can add a try catch throw around whatever you do and put a breakpoint into the catch, for debugging. Otherwise, not really as exceptions might get caught/logged somewhere later...

Comment: In normal .NET we got that: whatever unhandled exception happens in user code it stops the debugger on it. It works in MVC, WEbForms, WinForms, whatever forms..

Comment: Is there any way to throw the exception immediately in .NET Core Web API?